# How to make widgets expand vertically using QFormLayout?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt

I found some tutorial code online about `QFormLayout`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QWidget()

    l1 = QLabel("Name")
    nm = QLineEdit()

    l2 = QLabel("Address")
    add1 = QLineEdit()
    add2 = QLineEdit()
    fbox = QFormLayout()
    fbox.addRow(l1, nm)
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()

    vbox.addWidget(add1)
    vbox.addWidget(add2)
    fbox.addRow(l2, vbox)
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    r1 = QRadioButton("Male")
    r2 = QRadioButton("Female")
    hbox.addWidget(r1)
    hbox.addWidget(r2)
    hbox.addStretch()
    fbox.addRow(QLabel("sex"), hbox)
    fbox.addRow(QPushButton("Submit"), QPushButton("Cancel"))
    win.setLayout(fbox)

    win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: screenshots]

The right bottom one is what the original GUI looks like.

When I resize the widget horizontally, the right top one is what GUI looks like.

When I resize the widget vertically, the left one is what GUI looks like.

It seems those labels and buttons will follow the horizontal change, but fail to change as the main widget changes vertically. Is there any way to expand the widgets vertically with `QFormLayout` as well?